# Bean not getting overridden in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, spring-cloud, spring-test

I am trying to write and test an application that used spring-cloud with azure functions following this tutorial.
https://github.com/markusgulden/aws-tutorials/tree/master/spring-cloud-function/spring-cloud-function-azure/src/main/java/de/margul/awstutorials/springcloudfunction/azure

I am tryign to write a testcase and override the bean.
Here is the application class having function and handler Bean function.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.package" })

public class DataFunctions extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<GenericMessage<Optional<String>>, Data> {

@FunctionName("addData")
public HttpResponseMessage addDataRun(
        @HttpTrigger(name = "add", methods = {
                HttpMethod.POST }, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.FUNCTION) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
        final ExecutionContext context) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a POST request.");

    try {
        handleRequest(new GenericMessage<Optional<String>>(request.getBody()), context);
    } catch (ServiceException ex) {
        ErrorMessage em = new ErrorMessage();
        return request.createResponseBuilder(handleException(ex, em)).body(em).build();
    }
    return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}

@Autowired
MyService mService;

@Bean
public Consumer<GenericMessage<Optional<String>>> addData() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return req -> {
        SomeModel fp = null;
        try {
            fp = mapper.readValue(req.getPayload().get(), SomeModel.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceException(e);
        }

        mService.addData(fp);
    };
}
```

}

I want to test by overriding the above bean.

Cosmosdb spring configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableDocumentDbRepositories
public class CosmosDBConfig extends AbstractDocumentDbConfiguration {

    @Value("${cosmosdb.collection.endpoint}")
    private String uri;

    @Value("${cosmosdb.collection.key}")
    private String key;

    @Value("${cosmosdb.collection.dbname}")
    private String dbName;

    @Value("${cosmosdb.connect.directly}")
    private Boolean connectDirectly;

    @Override
    public DocumentDBConfig getConfig() {
        ConnectionPolicy cp = ConnectionPolicy.GetDefault();
        if (connectDirectly) {
            cp.setConnectionMode(ConnectionMode.DirectHttps);
        } else {
            cp.setConnectionMode(ConnectionMode.Gateway);
        }
        return DocumentDBConfig.builder(uri, key, dbName).connectionPolicy(cp).build();
    }
}
```

Here is the configuration

```
@TestConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
@Profile("test")
@Import({DataFunctions.class})
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean(name="addData")
    @Primary
    public Consumer<GenericMessage<Optional<String>>> addData() {
        return req -> {
            System.out.println("data mock");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DocumentDBConfig getConfig() {
        return Mockito.mock(DocumentDBConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Finally the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@SpringBootTest //Enabling this gives initialization error.
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class TempTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DataFunctions func;

    @Mock
    MyService mService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    private Optional<String> createRequestString(final String res) throws IOException {
        InputStream iStream = TempTest.class.getResourceAsStream(res);
        String charset="UTF-8";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream, charset))) {
            return Optional.of(br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testHttpPostTriggerJava() throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> req = mock(HttpRequestMessage.class);
        final Optional<String> queryBody = createRequestString("/test-data.json");
        doNothing().when(mService).addData(Mockito.any(SomeModel.class));
        doReturn(queryBody).when(req).getBody();

        doAnswer(new Answer<HttpResponseMessage.Builder>() {
            @Override
            public HttpResponseMessage.Builder answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                HttpStatus status = (HttpStatus) invocation.getArguments()[0];
                return new HttpResponseMessageMock.HttpResponseMessageBuilderMock().status(status);
            }
        }).when(req).createResponseBuilder(any(HttpStatus.class));

        final ExecutionContext context = mock(ExecutionContext.class);
        doReturn(Logger.getGlobal()).when(context).getLogger();
        doReturn("addData").when(context).getFunctionName();

        // Invoke
        final HttpResponseMessage ret = func.addDataRun(req, context);

        // Verify
        assertEquals(ret.getStatus(), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

For this case instead of test configuration `addData` the actual bean is called from DataFunctions class. Also the database connection is also created when it should use the mocked bean from my test configuration. Can somebody please point out what is wrong in my test configuration?

Comment: If you use profile, you can mark you production beans `@ConditionalOnExpression("#{!environment.getProperty('spring.profiles.active').contains('test')}")`, it should prevent initialization of real beans, and of course you should restore the @SpringBootTest, possible it could be help with initialization errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the first part of cosmos db config loading by marking it with

```
@Configuration
@EnableDocumentDbRepositories
@Profile("!test")
public class CosmosDBConfig extends AbstractDocumentDbConfiguration {
   ...
}
```

Also had to mark the repository bean as optional in the service.

```
public class MyService {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MyRepository myRepo;
}
```

Didn't use any spring boot configuration other than this.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FunctionTest {
    ...
}
```

For the second part of providing mock version of Mock handlers, I simply made the test config file as spring application as below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boeing.da.helix.utm.traffic" })
@Profile("test")
public class TestConfiguration {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestConfiguration.class, args);
    }
    @Bean(name="addData")
    @Primary
    public Consumer<GenericMessage<Optional<String>>> addData() {
        return req -> {
            System.out.println("data mock");
        };
    }   
}
```

and made use of this constructor from azure functions library in spring cloud in my constructor

```
public class AppFunctions
        extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<GenericMessage<Optional<String>>, List<Data>> {
    public AppFunctions(Class<?> configurationClass) {
        super(configurationClass);
    }
}

public AzureSpringBootRequestHandler(Class<?> configurationClass) {
    super(configurationClass);
}
```

Hope it helps someone.